# "cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, sql

First i created this table name DEPARTMENT and afterwards i created Dept_Locations which has the foreign key reference in this table at Dnumber.

```
create table DEPARTMENT(
    Dname               varchar(20)     NOT NULL,
    Dnumber             int             NOT NULL,
    Mgr_ssn             char(9)         NOT NULL,
    Mgr_start_date      date            NOT NULL,
    Primary key(Dnumber),
    Unique(Dname)
);
```

Code for Dept_Locations table:

```
create table Dept_Locations(
    Dnum char(4),
    Dlocation varchar(16),
    primary key(Dnum,Dlocation),
    foreign key(Dnum) references DEPARTMENT(Dnumber));
```

Now when i execute this code for creating Dept_Locations I get an error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign key must be the same data type as the column it's referring to.

The column `Dnumber` in DEPARTMENT is `int`, and the column `Dnum` is defined as `char(4)` - but it must be defined as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Think the datatypes differ.

```
Dnum char(4)

Dnumber int
```

Answer (score 0):

You primary key and the column with the foreign key constraint are different sizes - try:

```
create table DEPARTMENT(
    Dname               varchar(20)     NOT NULL,
    Dnumber             char(4)          NOT NULL, # <-- Note the size change
    Mgr_ssn             char(9)         NOT NULL,
    Mgr_start_date      date            NOT NULL,
    Primary key(Dnumber),
    Unique(Dname)
);
```

(or update the other to match)